# Delete images along with deleting rows with Excel interop

Tags: excel, office-interop

My excel document contain images on the rows.
I am deleting various rows with `EntireRow.Delete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);`
Is there a way to also delete the images on those rows? (now they shifting down) Preferably only images whos center is in that row to prevent deleting images that were placed a little off.

I searched around a bit but I'm afraid what I want may not be possible.
Any advice or workaround is very welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You already noticed that images float above the worksheet.

I am not familiar with Interop, then I will show the VBA code and you still need to translate it.

You can find the bounds of the row with:

```vb
top = EntireRow.Top
bottom = EntireRow.Top + EntireRow.Height
```

Then you need to loop over the shapes to find which ones are inside the row:

```vb
sheet = EntireRow.Parent ' if you have the sheet already, use it.

For Each shape In sheet.Shapes
    mid_shp = shape.Top + shape.Height/2
    If mid_shp > top And mid_shp < bottom Then
       shape.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This looks interesting, I will check it out!

Comment: `var shapes = sheet.Shapes;` `foreach(var shape in shapes){}` shape has no useable attributes/functions in C#, unfortunately. ShapeRange is the same. But I understand how you meant to do it, will try to find a solution to the difference in addressing shapes.